# spring-cloud - Hystrix Stream with just Ribbon

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign, netflix-ribbon

With `spring-boot-starter-actuator` in a web application, where Ribbon/Feign Clients are used, hystrix stream/ endpoint is not enabled.

`HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration.HystrixWebConfiguration` is not activated even with the conditions being true.

How to enable hystrix stream for Feign/Ribbon?

Environment: Spring Boot 1.3.5.RELEASE, Spring Cloud Brixton.SR4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the `@EnableHystrix` to the context configuration?

Comment: Thank you. Works with `@EnableHystrix`. Made a wrong assumption that `@EnableFeignClients` would enable hystrix internally.